# Can I Implement Refresh Key With RemoteMediator using room database

Tags: android, android-paging-3, android-paging-library, remote-mediator

i want to use a room database as a datasource for the paging source of paging 3 library i saw all the implementation a round google and forums but they all get PagingSource from dao, they pass a query and get the PagingSource ready but i want to implement my own to handle the refresh key is that possible.
and if the remoteMediator handle it as i don't have to please tell me

the reason my i want to do that is that when the refresh happened i want to refresh the ui not remove all data from local i want to just make the old data before referesh invisible to the pagging source
can handling refresh key do that ?